# SQLAlchemy 2.0 version of User.query.get(1) in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**The Problem**

The `Query.get()` method is [deprecated in SQLAlchemy 2.0](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.get). Accordingly, the [Flask-SQLAlchemy query interface is considered legacy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/legacy-query/).  Thus, running `User.query.get(1)` in my Flask-SQLAlchemy project gives the legacy warning shown below:

```
>>> User.query.get(1)
<stdin>:1: LegacyAPIWarning: The Query.get() method 
is considered legacy as of the 1.x series of SQLAlchemy 
and becomes a legacy construct in 2.0. The method is 
now available as Session.get() (deprecated since: 2.0) 
(Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)
<User spongebob>
```

**My Question**

What is the new, SQLAlchemy 2.0-compatible version of `User.query.get(1)` in Flask-SQLAlchemy? More specifically, why does the Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation recommend Approach #2 below, even though Approach #1 appears to be the new version based on my reading of the SQLAlchemy 2.0 migration guide?

**Approach #1: `db.session.get(User, 1)`**

This first approach comes from the SQLAlchemy docs, specifically the [SQLAlchemy 2.0 Migration - ORM Usage](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-orm-usage) guide. Translating the "2.0 style" example in that guide to my Flask-SQLAlchemy project yields the following code, which works fine:

```
>>> db.session.get(User, 1)
<User spongebob>
```

This approach with `session.get()` isn't mentioned in the Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.0.x documentation as far as I can tell, except briefly in the API reference section on `get_or_404`.

**Approach #2: `db.session.execute(db.select(User).filter_by(id=1)).scalar()`**

This approach comes from the [Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/legacy-query/), which suggests using `session.execute(select(...))` as a replacement for the legacy `Model.query` and `session.query`. This works fine, too:

```
>>> db.session.execute(db.select(User).filter_by(id=1)).scalar()
<User spongebob>
```

**Approach #1 vs. Approach #2 vs. Legacy Approach**

Approach #1 (`db.session.get(User, 1)`) appears to be most similar to the Legacy Approach (`User.query.get(1)`) because it caches the result in the `session` the first time it runs and won't emit additional calls to the database unnecessarily.  This can be seen in the REPL with the echo turned on, i.e. `db.engine.echo = True`. In contrast, Approach #2 (`session.execute(select(...))`) goes to the database each time, as expected.

**My Set Up / Environment**

1. Versions: Flask 2.2.2, Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.0.3, and SQLAlchemy 2.0.1 in a virtual environment with Python 3.11.
2. I'm using the project structure defined in the Flask Mega-Tutorial, specifically [Part IV Database](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database).

Comment: Approach #1 is the way, for the reason that  you have described - it checks the session before querying the database.

Answer (score 12):

According to https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#orm-query-get-method-moves-to-session

The Query.get() method remains for legacy purposes, but the primary interface is now the Session.get() method:

```
# legacy usage
user_obj = session.query(User).get(5)
```

**Migration to 2.0**

In 1.4 / 2.0, the Session object adds a new Session.get() method:

```
# 1.4 / 2.0 cross-compatible use
user_obj = session.get(User, 5)
```

In which compatible with flask_sqlalchemy, this should work well

```
user_obj = db.session.get(User, 5)
```

Comment: This is a solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found an approach that avoids using the deprecated method while still letting you call a method on the model rather than having to access `db.session`.

First I noted that you can access the session from the model:

```
>>> MyModel.query.session
<sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x7f1d9fe86c10>
```

So you *could* use the following verbose code:

```
>>> MyModel.query.session.get(MyModel, value)
<MyModel 1>
```

But that's not particularly elegant. Instead, in my case, I already made all my models inherit from a custom class I called `IDMixin`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SqlAlchemy()


class IDMixin:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class MyModel(IDMixin, db.Model):
    field = db.column(db.String(50))
```

So I added a classmethod to that mixin:

```
class IDMixin:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_by_id(cls, id_):
        return cls.query.session.get(cls, id_)
```

Now I can retrieve individual objects as follows:

```
>>> MyModel.get_by_id(1)
<MyModel 1>
```

It took a bit of custom code but I'm happy with the result.

Comment: I like your idea, you can also use a manager (like in django, which follows the repository and unit of work patterns) to encapsulate all db operations, like get_by_id.

Answer (score 0):

Working with a Flask App with user registration, I came across this problem. The [Flask login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works) documentation has an example that has a small error:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)
                ^^^ not correct
```

So, I changed it to:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
                ^^^^^^^^^ deprecated
```

Finally, I used Approach #1 and everything worked smoothly:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return db.session.get(User, int(user_id))
```

Comment: This is offtopic,  but it's not an error. flask-login has no idea what db/orm setup you have and sample query in `load_user` is not production ready, but provided as example. In production you write your own query on your own ORM to load the user.by id / token.