# What is the proper way to query in flask-sqlalchemy 3.0?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365194/sqlalchemy-2-0-version-of-user-query-get1-in-flask-sqlalchemy)  on Stack Overflow mentions well, that the `Query.get()` method is considered legacy. I tried to look for the correct way to query from now on, and my question is: Which one of these approaches should I be using in my Flask apps and why? Should I keep using the flask-sqlalchemy framework, or should I use the basic SQLalchemy?

All these lines are being run from `with app.app_context()` block and all of them have the same outcome - they return a User object:

1. `user = User.query.get(1)` the old way of doing things (mentioned [here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/queries/#legacy-query-interface))
2. `user = db.session.get(User, 1)` mentioned in OP
3. `user = db.session.scalars(db.select(User).filter_by(id=1)).first()` mentioned [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#selecting-orm-entities-and-columns)
4. `user = db.session.execute(db.select(User).filter_by(id=1)).scalars().first()` mentioned in [flask-sqlalchemy docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/queries/#legacy-query-interface)
5. `user = db.get_or_404(User, 1)` mentioned also there.

From what I've understood, the approach (4) is recomended by flask-sqlalchemy. It's just weird to me, that a new solution would need such ugly, confusing and not-readable syntax, compared to (1) or (2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after more research, I found the following answers:

1. Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.x [bumped up the version of SQLAlchemy to 1.4.x](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/changes/#version-3-0-0).
2. A lot of SQLAlchemy functionality is "bundled" into Flask-SQLAlchemy's `SQLAlchemy` object. More on that [here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy). This means, that I do not have to import keywords such as `Column`, `session`, `select`; they are available using

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.session
```

3. Knowing that, [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#) on SELECT statements are finally useful (I am linking docs to version 2.0.7, because it appears to me, that it's written more nicely here than in 1.4.x. If I was to find some inconsistency, I would mention it here).
4. [`select()` is now the way to perform queries](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/index.html#sqlalchemy-unified-tutorial).

In practice, I think this is the way to perform queries now; I am writing it out here for (my own) future easier reference. I am also using my syntax from Flask-SQLAlchemy, using `db.` described earlier:

1. `db.session.get(User, 1)` to select using primary keys, successor to `User.query.get(1)`. Returns `User` object.
2. `db.session.scalars(db.select(User).where(User.email == "name@example.com")).first()` to select using other columns, successor to `User.query.filter_by(email="name@example.com").first()`. Returns 'User' object.
3. `db.session.scalars(db.select(User)).all()` to get all Users, successor to `User.query.all()`. Returns `list` of `User` objects.

Comment: I was also struggling with this and find the new syntax ugly compared to the "legacy" way of Model.query.
The new way also says to set up like this:

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
  pass

db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)

Which is also more convoluted.
I'm considering dropping using Flask-SQLAlchemy it for straight SQLAlchemy if I have to go change all my code anyway. What did you end up doing?